# WPF get data values from a CollectionView and put them in variables

Tags: wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I want to know how to get values from a table in a `DataViewCollection` and put them into variables.

I have bought and read many books and bought and watched many videos but not show me what I want.  They all show you how to display data on the screen in controls or objects.

Comment: While this is a good question, it would be better to show an example of code that doesn't work so we can help you fix it.